# CakePHP pre-filling form data doesn't seem to work

Tags: cakephp

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

A user fills out a form, saves a record.  At some later date they wish to "clone" this record, but may want to make a few tweaks.  This "clone" functionality should direct them to a form that is pre-filled with the previous record's data so that they can review it, edit as needed, and submit it as a new record.

What I'm trying:

I've modified my add() function to accept a parameters:

```
function add($cloneid = NULL)
```

Then created a Clone link that sends them to **siteurl/model/add/id_to_clone**

Then, I get the data from that model:

```
$clone_source = $this->Model->findById($cloneid);
$this->data['Model']['field1'] = $clone_source['Model']['field1'];
```

and so on.  Based on Google searching and other posts, this should work.  But what actually happens is that upon clicking the 'Clone' link, the user is directed and the form submits itself immediately (failing to save the record, since it fails validation) and the user never actually sees the form.

What am I doing wrong?  (Also I should note, there are relational models present, but I don't think this should be the cause of any problems...I hope).

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint the cause of this without the whole code. Can you update the question with the add function, the add form, and maybe the link 'Clone', that directs the user to the form that submits immediately?

Comment: in addition, can you change $this->data['Model']['field1'] to $this->request->data['Model']['field1'], and then try to execute your code.

Comment: What @AyoAkinyemi suggest will only work for versions v2.x. Please mention your cake version.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are pre-populated using the `$this->request->data` array.

In order for your form to be populated you will need to set some data to the request.

So you'll be better off with the following.

```
$this->request->data = $this->Model->findById($id);
```